# JavaMail IMAP IDLE vs polling reliability

Tags: java, email, imap

I want to program a server process which processes incoming emails. To do this, I see two options 1. Polling and 2. Email Push with the IMAP IDLE feature. Both can be done with JavaMail. I tend to implement the whole with IMAP IDLE, but I have some concerns about the reliability. As it will run as server process 7x24, it would be fatal if the service simply remains, freezes or becomes unresponsive.

So finally the question is,can the IMAP IDLE feature safely be implemented in a server process, or with regard to reliability and stability, is the polling approach the better solution?

Answer (score 2):

IMAP Idle does-not runs 24x7, usually almost all the mailers have a timeout defined for IDLE, something like 30 minutes And  if the server is not doing that then it could be a big bottle-neck since the device like imap/ipad and some other clients instantiates several instances simultaneously and may or may-not close the connection and in case there is no IDLE timeout then the server would be piled up soo many unterminated and useless connections effectively choking th entire system.

Polling could be good option but that might again slow down the services since every time the entire mailbox of user need to be scanned for any mail activity.

I would suggest to use IDLE since it runs with minimal resources(at server) and is effective for any updates and dont forget to disconnect the connection from client end before 30 minutes(time-out value, have heard of different issues)